# Checking for presence of an item without using expect

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In my web application, the *Sign Out* link is only shown once the user has logged in - it's not present on the login page.

In my Protractor tests, I want to make sure the user is logged in - which means that in my first test, I have to log in. To check whether the user is logged in or needs to log in, I want to check for the presence of the *Sign Out* link.

I don't want to do this using `expect`, since not having the *Sign Out* link present on the page is perfectly acceptable, it just means that I have to log in.

What I'm looking for is a way to implement an `if` scenario in my test (in a `beforeEach` function) - pseudo code:

```
if (!signOut.isPresent()) {
    login();
}
```

So far, I haven't found an easy way to do this - all of the checks for presence of an item in the page's DOM seem to rely on `expect`, which throws an exception when the item is not present on the page.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @alb-i986 got me on the right track. After looking at the `findElement` API, I found two references on how to do the error handling for a this function:

- https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebelement
- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/485#issuecomment-33951648

Protractor is returning a *promise* from the `findElement` function, and the promise's `then` function (which is called once the promise is resolved) takes two callback arguments:

- The first one is called when the promise is resolved successfully, i.e. the element was found on the page.
- The second one is optional. When it's not provided, the standard error handling takes place in case the element was not found. This means that the *No Such Element* exception is thrown. When providing the callback, it's your own responsibility to handle the error there. The error object is provided as a parameter to that callback.

Making use of the second (optional) callback, you can decide to handle or ignore the error:

```
protractor.getInstance().findElement(by.css(".signout-button"))
    .then(function(element) {
        // The element was found on the page - click it.
        element.click();
    }, function(error) {
        // Sign out button is not present - handle the error or ignore it
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just catch the exception.

Or use [findElements](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) and check if the returned list of elements is empty, which means the element is not present.

(Not sure about the second solution cause I don't know Protractor, but findElements is what you would use in Java)

Comment: Your reference to the `findElement` API helped me to find the solution. I've added my own answer with a working example for JavaScript/Protractor.